# RDLC Report Designer VSIX file won't install

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I am running VS 2017 and have ReportViewer installed. However, it won't let me modify RDLC files I have in a legacy project graphically; it just shows the XML. I am trying to install RDLC Report Designer and have the Microsoft.RdlcDesigner.vsix file downloaded from the Marketplace, but when I double-click on it in Windows Explorer, it starts to install, but then the installation window closes abruptly and nothing gets done. I have also tried installing it through Extensions and Updates from within VS, and it claims to be installed, but when I shut down and restart VS, it still isn't there.

What do I need to do to get RDLC Report Designer installed?

Note that I am able to create Report Server projects and RDLs, but I need to modify an RDLC getting data from a class file.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody told me where the VSIX log file was located, and I discovered that I need Admin privilege to install it. You would think Windows would have warned me about this, and/or displayed a message when it attempted the installation.